"Win" and "Alt" Key Not Working in VMware Windows guest on Linux Host
Host OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Guest OS: Windows 10 Pro
Guest OS Software: VMware-tools-12.5.0
VMware Version: VMware-Workstation-Full-17.6.1-24319023.x86_64.bundle
In windows guest, press WIN key will trigger my host event and Alt+Tab is NOT working in guest OS either.
I think Ctrl is working in guest OS because Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V is working in Notepad.
Please help, thanks a lot.

If you cannot get this fixed in VMware, does VirtualBox have same issues?

@DrMoishePippik VirtualBox works fine for all special keys. But VirtualBox guest does NOT support opengl on Linux host. All my opengl apps can not be ran on VirtualBox guest OS. That's why I am trying VMware now. Opengl apps are working fine in VMware guest OS.
